# is it 'wrong' to upvote lots of answers from the same author to grant them bonus rep?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I've recently come across a few really well written and researched answers contributed by low rep users.

I feel like my solitary upvote isn't sufficient reward for their efforts. (Yes, I know that truly good answers will attract votes from other users, but in less active tags this can take a while.)

Is it 'wrong' to go to the user's page and go through other answers and questions they have worked on to give them 'bonus' rep?

I wouldn't upvote obviously bad answers, but if the answer is at least ok - or if the answer is an area I don't have experience in - is this 'reverse-gaming' or a legitimate technique to help great new SO-ers?

Edit: thanks for the feedback. It's a good thing I asked first...

Might have to ask a new question about how to help people 'level up' in quieter areas of SO.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [Downvoter says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41082/is-it-wrong-to-upvote-lots-of-answers-from-the-same-author-to-grant-them-bonus/41083#41083), too many votes will trip the anomaly filter.

Nor is it reasonable to vote for the authors other posts because you liked one in particular. **However**, it is *entirely* reasonable to go to their profile page and spend some time hunting up other deserving work of theirs and then vote for *those good* posts.

Comment: This is a dangerous suggestion. See Jeff's comment on my answer please. You maybe doing more harm than good.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I know there's a few users who consistently post good answers and I'll often frequent their page to learn from them. It's a shame that there's a downside to this.

Answer (score 15):

It is absolutely wrong.

You should upvote (or downvote) posts based only on the post, and not the author.

Also, keep in mind that there's a nocturnal process that detects anomalous vote patterns (including multiple votes from the same person) and reverses them.

Comment: +1 - I'm not totally opposed to giving someone an extra upvote or two on *deserving* answers, but do keep in mind that if you do this more than a couple of times you'll just end up costing that person when *all* of your votes for them are removed as anomalous.

Comment: I was going to upvote this answer, but then I saw who wrote it.

Comment: This is such a great answer that I will upvote all your other answers now to reward you.

Comment: @Daniel - lol, but downvoter doesn't need the extra rep...

Comment: it doesn't just reverse them -- it invalidates ALL votes from you to that user, for all time, permanently. So my advice is to tread very carefully.

Comment: @Jeff, How do you know if you have been hit by the "detects anomalous vote patterns" check, as I often find another user thats have asked a lot of questions that I think are worth upvoting.   (People do have the some interests as each other)

Comment: @jeff, does it invalidate future votes also? are you "banned" from voting that user again?

Comment: @Ian I am willing to bet that the time frame between votes matters too. I imagine the script looks for more serial actions, such as me going and downvoting or upvoting all of your answers in a short time frame (short enough that it wouldn't be possible for me to read them all).

Comment: @jared - maybe we need a field on the profile screen for reading speed...

Comment: @Jeff: I'd be willing to bet that some of the absolutely dreadful users (sh\*\*\* being one) get a tremendous number of downvotes removed because of this algorithm. Perhaps it is a little too heavy-handed in acting permanently.

Comment: @Jared,  the hard bit with is I often open lots of tabs, then read all the questions on a subject and then upvote the best questions.  So it is hard to relate speed of voting with "no time to read"